# How to free increased physical memory consumption

Tags: memory-leaks

I am running ERP software, which is allocating physical memory 300mb on startup, but after generating some reports, consumption of physical memory by that application increasing rapidly and consuming upto 700mb, but after closing the same report, its not getting free the same until I close the application.

Is there any way to free/ retrieve physical memory consumed by application through c# programming.

Comment: what you mean by retrieve the memory consumed ?